# How to return back to original page after redirect?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-sessions

I'm building a webpage that needs an age-gate.
For this to work I'm using Django sessions. The view checks if the age-gate has been passed and otherwise redirects the user back to the age-gate.
After A user passed the age-gate I want to redirect them back to the page they came from. How do I do this?
I tried using `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` but that did not work.
My view looks like this:

```
`def main_view(request):
    if request.session.has_key('agegate'):
        random_category = random.choice(Category.objects.all())
        random_picture = random.choice(CoreImages.objects.all())

        context = {
            'image' : random_picture,
            'category' : random_category,
            'bottles': Bottle.objects.all(),
        }
        return render(request,'Academy/home.html', context)
    else:
        return redirect('/preview/agegate')`
```

The age-gate view looks like this:

```
def age_gate_view(request):

    next_url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    form = AgeGateForm()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AgeGateForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            request.session['agegate'] = 'welcome'
            return HttpResponseRedirect(next_url)
    
    context = {
        'form':form,
    }

    return render(request,'Academy/agegate.html', context)
```

Comment: Well it will go forth and back: indeed you redirect to the `age_gate_view` which will then refer back, and then the `main_view` redirect again to the `age_gate_view` and so on, until the browser has had enough and no longer wants to change course.

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: please give more details what exactly you mean with "did not working".

Answer (score 2):

In Django, there's a convention of using the `next` url parameter to keep track of the original url.

So, you can do something like this:

```py
def main_view(request):
    # ...
    return redirect('/preview/agegate?next=/current-view-url/')
```

Next, in the age-gate view, you can read the value of the `next` parameter to redirect to the ogirinal url.

```py
def age_gate_view(request):
    next_url = request.GET.get('next')
    if next_url is None:
        # fallback to HTTP_REFERER header
        # or home page in case header is not present
        next_url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/')
    # ...
```